# MaxHeapSize in Java

Tags: java, heap-memory

I run command in window machine

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | findstr /i "HeapSize PermSize ThreadStackSize
```

and got below value for `MaxHeapSize`

```
2118123520
```

which is `2020MB` however, when I call `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()` , it gives me `259522560` only i.e. `247MB` .

Can anyone please suggest why I'm getting this mismatch ?

Comment: I guess you have an 8 GB machine so the default is 2 GB. You have reduced the maximum heap size when you run your program so you only get ~256 MB because that is what you set it to.

Comment: Have you tried with `-Xmx100m  -Xms100m`

Comment: Perfect . But I'm using eclipse IDE and didn't change any setting . do  you know how to change maximum heap size in eclipse IDE ?

Comment: thanks -Xmx100m  -Xms100m worked for me now .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your last comment

> I'm using eclipse IDE and didn't change any setting . do you know how to change maximum heap size in eclipse IDE ?

Set the VM arguments found under Run configuration.

**VM arguments are typically values that change the behaviour of the Java Virtual Machine (JVM). For example, the -Xmx256M argument allows the Java heap to grow to 256MB.**

For more info have a look at [Eclipse launching program and VM arguments](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Flaunchers%2Farguments.htm)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone please suggest why I'm getting this mismatch ?

The `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()` call is returning the maximum heap size for the current JVM.  This is determined by either the -Xmx command line option (e.g. for the `java` command) or a platform specific default.

The command you are running is giving the maximum allowed value for the -Xmx commandline option on your platform.

Clearly these are different things.  Furthermore, the numbers are usually different.